# Can I get credit for lewd gestures at people who are already trying to kill me?

Tags: saints-row-the-third, achievements

In Saints Row 3, one of the Saintsbook challenges (and an achievement) is taunting gang members.  I can go around and taunt enemy gang members, but I only seem to get a popup (and credit in the Saintsbook) when I make suggestive gestures towards gang members who weren't already angry with me.  Is there any way to taunt a gang member who arrived as a result of my "Gang Wanted" level being high?

If that's the case, are there any tricks to speeding up the amount of taunts I can do against gang members in a given amount of time?

Comment: Realistically, you taunt people who are unwilling to fight you for one reason or another. If they are already at you with guns blazing, then taunting really isn't gonna do much.

Comment: Oh YEAH?  Whatchu gonna do about it?? *makes lewd gesture*

Comment: Don't know. Pretend to trip and fall flat on my face? lol

Comment: @James, I also take offense at any use of the word "realistic" with respect to Saints Row 3.  Let's just say *realism and this game are no longer on speaking terms*

Comment: It's questions like this (and most of the rest for this game) that make me almost want to play it, even though it is so outside my normal range of things I play. Yay Gaming, broadening my gaming horizons!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm working on this challenge as well. Your findings are correct in that you **only get credit for taunting a gang member if you do not already have aggro from them**. You also cannot get credit for taunting your *own* gang members. It must be a rival gang, though you can *compliment* your own gang members and have that count for both the challenge and the achievement.

In order to speed this up, I did as follows. This is easier if you don't already control every area because you're more likely to find random gang members walking around in areas you don't control.

**What you should have to speed this up:**

- A purchased building that's fairly close to the border of uncontrolled territory
- A couple Health/Regen upgrades to be able to survive the onslaught of gang members (Combat is decent too. Basically, whatever will up your survivability)

**What you should do**

1. Travel to an area you don't control and **look for a gang member walking around to taunt**
2. **Taunt them**
3. **Gain 3 stars of notoriety by killing more gang members**. This is enough to bring a decent number of gang members (and lieutenants, if you still need to grind those for the challenges). More than that and you risk getting killed outright, but you can of course grab more if you know you can survive.
4. **Start moving towards the building you own** (the plan is to go in their to clear your notoriety)
5. Before you clear your notoriety, **blow up all their vehicles**. Otherwise, when you clear your notoriety, they'll hop in their cars and speed away. Hopefully, you should have a decent number of gang members following you, so the casualties from the exploding cars shouldn't hamper you too much.
6. **Run inside and clear your notoriety**
7. **Run back outside and taunt one of the gang members**, get your credit for taunting them, then **kill them** because **you won't get credit for taunting the same member twice**.
8. **Repeat Steps 6 & 7 until everyone is dead**
9. **Repeat steps 1 through 5**

Since you only have to taunt 50 gang members, this hopefully shouldn't take too long. In addition, it will go towards the `Love/Hate Relationship` achievement.

If you already have 100% control, I'm not sure if you will be able to use this method exactly, but the principle of aggro+pulling should still work.

Alternatively, rather than trying to grind this challenge all at once, it may be more sanity-saving to just stop whenever you see a gang member walking on the sidewalk and taunt them during your regular gameplay. Again though, it'll become more difficult to find the random gang members as you take over more areas.

Comment: Do I get credit for taunting my own gang members?  I think I did in SR2, and it was much easier than trying on rival gang members.

Comment: @agent86 After some testing, it seems not. :( I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I noted a few things - one is that brutes and specialists count.  Second, if you can get a group of them to stand together, you can get credit for more than one taunt at once.  I also found that moving their cars before blowing them up caused fewer gang casualties.  Thanks for your tips!

Comment: Oh, and if you need noteriety and you can't get it (ie, there are no more random gang spawns) try starting a "mayhem" or "drug trafficking" diversion in that gang's (former) territory.  They'll generally give you at least a couple of wanted stars with that faction.  Once the gang has you surrounded, quit the activity.  This sometimes resets the wanted level, so make sure you act fast to blow up vehicles/gang members and bring it back up again.

Comment: "only get credit for taunting a gang member if you do not already have aggro from them" - This isn't true, though. I just finished this achievement in the midst of a gigantic gun fight. Just to let you know (:

Answer (score 2):

Even though this has been answered, I just wanted to add that you can get taunts even when engaged in gun fights with other gangs. I have the health/regen maxed out, and then I went to one of the Mayhem challenges with opposite gangs in it. Then I just ran around killing and taunting the other members. It's a bit more tricky to get the taunt when they are firing at you, and knocking you over, but it can be done.